# how to get an objects property

Tags: php

ive got an object that looks like this with print_r():

```
SimpleDOM Object ( [0] => continent )
```

i wonder how i could get the continent as a string?

i have tried gettype($object[0]);

it still says its an object.

i just want to get the string "continent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this SimpleDOM](http://code.google.com/p/mrclay/source/browse/branches/oldies/php/SimpleDOM.php?r=6) the one you're using?

If so, it looks like that value would be stored in the `_Element::$tagName` variable.  So maybe try this?

```
echo $object[0]->tagName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not familar with SimpleDOM but it would  seem to me that its something similar in implementation to SimpleXMLElement. If this is the case then casting the object to a string should get you what you want:

`$continent = (string) $object;`

or from its parent node you can probably access it like so:

`$continent = $parent->continent;`

These are only guesses though. I would taka  look at the SimpleDOM documentation.

Comment: @gordon: in that case id avoid that library like the plague :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
get_class($object[0])
```

But i've not understood if you want the class name or other.